# TypeError: this is undefined in rect js while passing BigNumber in solana RPC Request

Tags: reactjs, blockchain, solana, decentralized-applications, solana-cli

i am getting this is undefined at BN while making RPC request to a function in solana smart contract

'''
let token1Amount = BN(token1_amount);
let token2Amount = BN(token2_amount)

```
  const add_liquidity = await router_program.rpc.addLiquidity(
    token1Amount,
    token2Amount,
    {
      accounts: {
        // poolAccount: pool_Account.publicKey, //account which stores the individual pair data
        userToken1Account: usetoken1_account,
        userToken2Account: usetoken2_account,
        poolToken1Account: new PublicKey(tokenaccount_1),
        poolToken2Account: new PublicKey(tokenaccount_2),
        owner: provider.wallet.publicKey,
        tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
        // systemProgram : SystemProgram.programId ,
        // associatedTokenProgram: spl.ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
        // rent: anchor.web3.SYSVAR_RENT_PUBKEY,
        tokensProgram: TOKEN_ID,
        // poolProgram: pair.programId,
        // pairAccount: pairAccount.publicKey
      },
      // signers: [provider]
    }
  );
```

'''

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a shot in the dark, but I think you need `new` so that your `BN`s have a `this` context, so instead try:

```
let token1Amount = new BN(token1_amount);
let token2Amount = new BN(token2_amount);
```